# Firebase Hosting: Can't find server in some Regions

Tags: firebase, dns, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I've deployed a site on Firebase Hosting with Vue.js, it's been working on my device without issues, but now I've discovered that a couple of first-time users are getting a "Can't find server" error in the browser. Everything is live, and I, in addition to others that've been on it before, can access it without issues.

I've checked if firebase hosting is down or having issues, it doesn't seem to be.
I've put in the actual IP address that the site is hosted on, in addition to the firebase-web-app domain, both of these are still getting the error and can't load the site.
I went onto isdown.me and it's telling me the site is down despite the fact that I can, in addition to other users, still run it.
I've also cleared my browser cache and reloaded the site, it still works

Comment: How do I catch issues like this earlier? So far I've been using a "If it runs on my laptop, it works" approach, but now I have no idea how many users have tried, but failed, to enter my site...

Comment: Without exact retails where we can reproduce the issue, we can only guess what your solution can be.. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reponse, read the article, not sure how exactly I could make this easily reproducible? Hosting a web-application in firebase and then testing its response from different locations is quite complex

Comment: SO is a coding specific site; write some code and when you get stuck, post it and your troubleshooting and we'll take a look. I know you're looking for help but there's not a whole lot we can do here to assist - it sounds like a DNS issue but it could be 100 other things as well and it doesn't sound like it's code related - more of a site setting issue.